# How to "click through" fixed overlay div, without disabling its pointer events

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a use case where I need to overlay fixed div over canvas element. This div is used to listen for scroll event and then transfer that data to canvas it is covering. Simplified html for these could look like following:

```
<canvas style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"></canvas>
<div style="position: fixed; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; top: 0; left: 0;"></div>
```

I ran across an issue. My canvas is also interactive, it has button elements and other stuff like that, unfortunately I had to implement scrolling behaviour this way for better performance and to keep default browser behaviours like "bounce scroll" on ios.

Is it at all possible to have this approach but also translate all mouse / touch event from the div to canvas behind it?

Comment: does your div always cover the canvas completely?

Comment: @AnzorAsadov It gets created only for views that need scrolling functionality, but in those cases yes, it covers them completely (i.e. there are 2 divs one the size of canvas, the other inside of it the size of content that triggers scroll behaviour on its parent div).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay, so you cannot really pass a click event programmatically and have x and y coordimates (as seen in the fiddle I attached).

What you can do is define global vars that store x and y coords on click of div. and then trigger click on canvas like this:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('#theDiv')
var canvas = document.querySelector('#theCanvas')
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

div.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
  console.log('div clicked', event); // event.clientX and event.clientY have correct values
  x = event.clientX;
  y = event.clientY;
  canvas.click();
});

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log('canvas clicked', x, y, event); // event.clientX and event.clientY are both 0
})
```

Here is the fiddle, where you can see it in action (I have added some styles to differentiate between the div and canvas)

https://jsfiddle.net/m1n4xave/10/